# Get data attribute if element exists in the page

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="content-datas" data-load-content="rooms-list"></div>
```

And this JS:

```
if($('[data-load-content]').length) {
    var datas = $(this).attr('data-load-content');
    alert(datas);
    $('#content-datas').load('assets/php/ajax/' + datas + '.php');
}
```

Could you please tell me why `datas = 'undefined'` ?

Comment: this has no meaning here. use var datas = $('[data-load-content]').attr('data-load-content');

Comment: Thanks for your help @Ali.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `this` in your code would refer to the `window` (assuming it's not in scope of anything else). To make `this` refer to the element with the `data` attribute, you could use `each()` to loop through them all. Also note that you should use `data()` to retrieve data attribute values through jQuery.

```
$('[data-load-content]').each(function() {
    var datas = $(this).data('load-content');
    alert(datas);
    $('#content-datas').load('assets/php/ajax/' + datas + '.php');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/y3a0vaLb/)

Answer (score 0):

Your are referencing `this`, which in that case refers to the window object, and not the intended element. So instead, try grabbing a reference to the element, like so:

```js
var $elem = $('[data-load-content]'); // grab reference here

if ($elem.length) { // check the reference's length
    var datas = $elem.attr('data-load-content'); // use the reference once again
    alert(datas);
    $('#content-datas').load('assets/php/ajax/' + datas + '.php');
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="content-datas" data-load-content="rooms-list"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope that helps!